# how to get value of individual component within c:foreach?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, foreach, icefaces

I have used c:foreach to iterate and display my inputtext where each inputtext has unique id, how do i get the individual id of the particular component or the one which user selected?

```
<c:forEach items="${gapMatch.text}" var="fill">
    <ice:outputText value="${fill.outputText}" />   
    <ice:inputText id="${fill.inputText}" onclick="popup.show();" >
</c:forEach>
```

I need this input text id in my managed bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you need but you could write a javascript function like this

```
function fun(id){  
     document.getElementById(id) etc
}


<ice:inputText id="${fill.inputText}" onclick="popup.show();"
onblur="fun(this.id);">
```

you can also bind your component to your backing bean and get the id.